# Neo4j creating a "middleware" plugin

Tags: neo4j

Im trying to create a plugin for neo4j that for every query to the data base it will be invoked and add some proprties to the created/updated nodes/relationships from the current query..

Simple use case: attach an `id` property for every created node/relationship(i know such plugin exsiste im trying to do something abit different)

After reading neo4j documentation about plugins all i found was how to extend the REST API but this is not my goal.

Anone know how to do that? 
Talking about neo4j 3.x

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your goal?

Comment: @MicTech My goal is to create something very similar to the UUID plugin of graphaware but instade of attaching id's to attach timestamps

Answer (score 1):

There is [GraphAware Framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) and its [UUID](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) plugin.

Here is the [great article](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html) how to write your own plugin.

GraphAware framework isn't ready for 3.0. It should be released next week (May 08 2016)

Comment: I know the graphaware and its UUID pulgin. And I already have a plugin doing exectly what i want. but the problem is that i dont want my plugin to be depend on the graphaware framework :\ since it looks to me like a unnecessary dependency